# Passing values into another class function gives zero when printed

Tags: c++, function, class, variables, return

I am trying to use int number_of_groups return and pass it into `djecja_reduta` function this is header file and then printing it for  first `karneval number_of_groups()` gives out normal values but `void djecja_reduta::number_of_groups()` gives 0 results

Example: I enter

```
number_home_groups = 200
number_foreign_groups = 300
```

on first call it gives me 500 sum but after when  `djecja_reduta::number_of_groups()` is called it gives me sum 0

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;
class karneval {
private:
    char name_carneval[30];
    int number_home_groups;
    int number_foreign_groups;
    int sum;
public:
    karneval() : number_home_groups(0),
                 number_foreign_groups(0),
                 sum(0)
    {
        strcpy(name_carneval, "");
    }

    void input();
    int number_of_groups();
};
void karneval :: input() {
    cout << "Input number home groups" << endl; 
    cin >> number_home_groups;
    cout << "input number_foreign_groups" << endl;
    cin >> number_foreign_groups;
}
int karneval:: number_of_groups() {
    sum = number_home_groupa + number_foreign_groups;
    cout << "Suma je:" << sum << endl;
    return sum;
}
class djecja_reduta:public karneval {
private:
    char mjesto_odrzavanja[30];
    int datum_odrzavanja;
public:
    void  number_of_groups();
};
void djecja_reduta:: number_of_groups(){
    karneval karneval;
    karneval.number_of_groups();
}
```

This is main file

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Header.h"
using namespace std;
int main() {
    int n;
    cout << "Inesert number of carnevals" << endl;
    cin >> n;
    karneval* a = new karneval[n];
    djecja_reduta* b = new djecja_reduta[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        cout << i + 1 << ".karneval" << endl;
        a[i].input();

    }
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        a[i].number_of_groups();
        b[i].number_of_groups();
    }
    delete[]a;
    a = NULL;
    delete[]b;
    b = NULL;
}
```

Output: 
Suma je:500
Suma je:0

Comment: Please [edit] your post to include the smallest program possible that shows these "very crazy results and random numbers." If possible, in that [MCVE], you'll likely get better answers if you can change your variable/class/function names into English.

Comment: @scohe001 I edited in english and added some more info

Answer (score 1):

Your constructor is not implemented correctly.

```
karneval() {
    char naziv_karnevala[30] = "";
    int broj_domacih_grupa = 0;
    int broj_stranih_grupa = 0;
    int suma = 0;
}
```

Here, the variables are function local variables. They are not the same as the member variables of the class. Consequently, the member variables are not initialized properly. That most likely causes problems downstream. Change it to:

```
karneval() : broj_domacih_grupa(0),
             broj_stranih_grupa(0),
             suma(0)
{
   std::strcpy(naziv_karnevala, "");
}
```

#### Update, in response to OP's comments

The output of

```
b[i].number_of_groups();
```

is always going to be zero with your code. In that function, you have

```
karneval karneval;
karneval.number_of_groups();
```

That `karneval` is independent of the the objects you allocated and provided input for in `main`.

Also, the objects in `a` in `main` and different than the objects in `b`. You are gathering input only for `a`. The objects in `b` have default state.

---

It is not clear to me what you are trying to do and what behavior you expect from the program. I am unable to provide any more constructive feedback because of that.

Comment: Did it the way you said still getting that crazy value in 
` void djecja_reduta:: number_of_groups(){
    karneval karneval;
    karneval. number_of_groups();
}` when called in main

Comment: @MarinSpudić, it's hard telling where the problem could be in your code without a [mcve].

Comment: added some more information with output too maybe it gets to you now pretty much my value of sum changed when called from another function in another class

Comment: After trying i changed constructors to be the way you said now i am getting value 0 there for my other function

Comment: @MarinSpudić, it's impossible for me to tell where the problem could be without a complete program and the sample input.

Comment: there i wrote you complete program  I need to print same values but from different functions inherited seems like i need to get these values from first function into other one but don't understand how

Comment: I need to output same values as in first function and djecja_reduta::number_of_groups() needs to have same output as first one so if sum is 500 they both need to output 500 as output